# SQL syntax error, cannot find the reason

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Thankyou in advance for answering this question, This is part af my code, it does not work.

```
 $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO 'users'
(
`ragionesociale`,
`user_name`, 
`user_email`, 
`pwd`, 
`nome`, 
`cognome`, 
`tel`, 
`tel2`, 
`website`, 
`date`, 
`users_ip`, 
`activation_code`, 
`piva`, 
`cf`, 
`azienda`) 

VALUES

(
'$data[ragionesociale]',
'$data[user_name]',
            '$user_email',
            '$sha1pass',
'$data[nome]',  
'$data[cognome]',
'$data[tel]',
'$data[tel2]',


'$data[website]' ,
now(),
'$user_ip',
'$activ_code',

$data[piva],$data[cf],
$data[azienda])";mysql_query($sql_insert)  or die("Insertion Failed:<br>$sql_insert<br>" . mysql_error());
```

and this is the given result:

```
INSERT INTO 'users' ( 
   `ragionesociale`, 
   `user_name`, 
   `user_email`,
   `pwd`, 
   `nome`, 
   `cognome`,
   `tel`, 
   `tel2`, 
   `website`, 
   `date`, 
   `users_ip`, 
   `activation_code`, 
   `piva`,
   `cf`, 
   `azienda`
) 
VALUES ( 
   'La Fabbrica dei Giochi', 
   'uuuuuuu', 
   'sssss@gmail.com', 
   'e258c8aac30eba143e1f3sssss6dc1cdc4d58ff1095', 
   'pietro', 
   'rossi', 
   '234234234', 
   '345.4346865', 
   'www.ssss.it' ,
    now(), 
   '212.124.171.131', 
   '9962', 
    2323232,
    tsssss6i819s, 
    1     )
```

Error message:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''users' 
(`ragionesociale`, `user_name`, `user_email`, `pwd`, `nome`, `cogno' at line 1
```

I cannot find what is wrong in this code and I'm wasting 2 hours....

Comment: Use backticks on `users` not single quotes, like you've done for columns.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the single-quotes with backticks:

```
$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO `users`
```

That should fix the issue.

Use backticks whenever possible. It'll help you prevent clash between reserved keywords (`password` for example).

Important: your query in it's current form is vulnerable to SQL injection. Consider escaping inputs with `mysql_real_escape_string()`, or even better, switch to using `PDO` or `mysqli`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an SQL string literal:

```
'users'
```

This is a table name:

```
users
```

This is a (MySQL) quoted table name:

```
`users`
```

The SQL standard would want `"users"` and various Microsoft databases would want `[users]`.

You can't INSERT into a string, you can't even think about it. Your SQL should look more like this:

```
$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO `users` ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the 'user' with

```
     `user`
```

. MySql doesn't recognize the usual

Answer (score 0):

I'll change 'users' to `users` plus the 2nd last field `$data[cf]` passes alphanumeric(`tsssss6i819s`) but  only assigns numeric. Change it to `,'$data[cf]'`. Maybe check the fields `azienda` and `piva` as well.